# How do you track phone click links on GA4 alone?

Tags: javascript, events, click, tracking, google-analytics-4

I have been searching for a way to track phone click links on GA4 WITHOUT the use of Google Tag Manager and have not been able to find any information. I know it's possible because otherwise how would 3rd party and GTM be able to track them

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Third parties and GTM track GA4 using the gtag.js library.
Here's the reference to how to use it: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs

Basically, you load the gtag library, you define the gtag() function as Google asks you to, then you call it like so:
`gtag('event', '<type>', {<parameters>});`

Obviously you can skip the whole library by forming the network requests manually and sending them to the collect endpoint.